# How to configure mysql in openempi?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, configuration

I want to configure mysql in openempi , 
I do't find any instruction regarding this configuration , they have given 
the instruction regarding to the postgresql . 
But according to their instruction regarding to the postgresqul , i made following changes into the jdbc.properties .

1. jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2. jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
3. jdbc.username=
4. jdbc.password=
5. hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

After changing that , when i start openempi , it created all the table from the "create_database_schema.sql" file but it is throwing error like following :

> Unknown column 'identifier0_.identifier_domain_description' in 'field list'
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityDefinitionManagerService' while setting bean property 'entityDefinitionManagerService'

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your localhost Mysql username/password. The default username in MySql is `root` and password as ``, If you have not modified those.

```
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

Comment: Hello Red Boy  , thanks for the quick replay  . 
I connected mysql successfully but some table is not created , because of that some spring related error is thrown by this tool called "openempi" .

Comment: OK, you meant some tables are not created, I think you need to scan source code and then execute those `create table sqls` manually. PostgreSQL is also open source, any particular reason of choosing Mysql?

Comment: my current system is using mysql database  , so all data is placed in there